# JQuery UI working on chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

My code is simple. It can be found at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2NF3/):

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#highlights">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#fineprint">Fine Print</a></li>
 <li><a href="#location">Location</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="highlights">
  highlights
</div>
<div id="fineprint">
  FiNEPRINT
</div>
<div id="location">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <address>ADDRESS</address>
    </li>
    <li>
   MAP
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

```
<button class="btn-placeorder"><span id="maplink">View map</span></button>

 <script>
 $(function(){
  $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
 $('#maplink').click(function(){
   $("#tabs").tabs("option","active",2);
 });
</script>
```

On Firefox you will notice, even in the fiddle the tabs don't change when the view map button is clicked.

I don't work with javascript much but I'd love to gain a better understanding of how to diagnose and solve these problems. Why is this happening, how can I solve it and how can I better educate myself?

Comment: I guess in chrome also it is not working

Comment: post the line where you include the jquery library js files and css files

Comment: +1 for requesting advice to diagnose. I hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First debugging tip: use tools. Most browser's nowadays include debugging tools you can call with <kbd>F12</kbd>. In Firefox, the short-cut is <kbd>Cmd+Opt+K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+K</kbd> though I recommend you open the add-on manager and install Firebug.

Second tip: check whether your code runs. The console API is a good start:

```
$('#maplink').click(function () {
    console.log("Button clicked");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
});
```

Nothing gets printed so your event is not being called. We can see it isn't attached directly to the button but to an inner `<span>`:

```
<button class="btn-placeorder"><span id="maplink">View map</span>
</button>
```

So we wonder: is there something wrong with onclick events on spans?

```
$("span").on("click", function(){
    console.log("click on span: %o", this);
});
```

Nothing printed, so there's apparently an issue. It is possible that the button is catching the onclick event?

```
<button class="btn-placeorder"><span id="maplink">View map</span>
    </button><span>Test span</span>
```

> click on span: `<span>`

So that it's! Weird... Well, why do you need a `<span>` in the first place?

```
$('.btn-placeorder').click(function () {
    console.log("Button clicked");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
});
```

It works! All we need now is some cleanup, such as assigning a proper ID to the `<button>` and getting rid of the redundant `<span>`.

Comment: > “Most browser's nowadays include debugging tools you can call with F12”… or in case of Firefox it’s cmd+opt+k/ctrl+shift+k.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert - You are right. I'm so used to Firebug that I even find it annoying that Firefox bundles its own tools :)

Comment: Thank you so much. You've solved my problem but more importantly taught a man how to fish. Have a fantastic day, best regards.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario You should really give Firefox’ tools a try, they have been improving continuously. I find myself using Firebug less and less often. Also, you get a 3D view…

Answer (score 1):

Your `#maplink` selector matches your inner `<span>` element, not its `<button>` parent.

Try writing:

```
<button id="maplink" class="btn-placeorder"><span>View map</span></button>
```

Instead of:

```
<button class="btn-placeorder"><span id="maplink">View map</span></button>
```

Comment: Do you know by chance why click events get trapped by `<button>` and are not transmitted to inner `<span>`?

Comment: @Álvaro, events normally bubble up, not down, but even then the `click` event should indeed originate on the `<span>` element and bubble up to the `<button>`. Looks like a UI implementation detail, I suspect the `<button>` captures `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, regardless of which descendant they occurred on, in order to implement its "pressed" state.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the id of the span with the actual class of the button, like this:

```
 $('.btn-placeorder').click(function(){
   $("#tabs").tabs("option","active",2);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if other answers are also correct, there could be another problem, the on click event handler registration is happening outside dom ready.

Try

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#maplink').click(function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", 2);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mjOft1CdF96U3thOCROO?p=preview)